# How to use FitBounds in deckgl on timer without npm and es6

Tags: javascript, mapbox, deck.gl

I've a deckGL map in a div-container.

```
let deckMap = new deck.DeckGL({
  mapStyle: 'https://basemaps.cartocdn.com/gl/positron-nolabels-gl-style/style.json',  
  initialViewState: {..
  },
  layers: [geoJSONLayer],
   getTooltip,
  controller: true,
  onViewStateChange: ({ viewState }) => {
    console.log("View Change");
    deckMap.setProps({ viewState })
  }
});
```

That thing "overlays"(?) my normal mapgl map

```
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  interactive: false,
  style: carto.basemaps.voyager,
  center: [INITIAL_VIEW_STATE.longitude, INITIAL_VIEW_STATE.latitude],
  zoom: INITIAL_VIEW_STATE.zoom
});
```

I'm running a cyclic download of a GeoJSON file and want to display the data. that already works. I also can calculate the bounds using bounds.extend.
But I can't find a way to set the zoom/fit the bounds.

**What I've tried**

1. `map.fitBounds` is just not working. It does nothing
2. `deckMap.fitBound` => unknown command
3. `WebMercatorViewport` => needs an import, import is unknown, including it requires app.js to be a module which screws the whole code.
4. `viewport=info.context` with that I could set viewport.fitBounds. Problem: What is info? I found this example in an event driven approach and info is the layer that the user interacts with. But simply using my `geoJSONLayer` does not work; fitBounds is not existent
5. Calculate zoom by hand. Can't find the algorithm anymore, but it was for GoogleEarth and I think it was broken in general.

How do I get the damned fitBounds working or - alternatively calculate the zoom for deckGL? I wasted 5 hours on that today!

Answer (score 3):

There is a working example of deck.gl `fitBounds` on map initialization [here](https://github.com/corrigancd/g6-in-react/blob/5f77aba9877d6a1d8a6a333f920c97c31b04edfd/pages/plugins/deckgl/map_deckgl.js#L12). To run:

- [Clone this repository](https://github.com/corrigancd/g6-in-react);
- Navigate into the repository and run `npm i && npm start`;
- Go to `http://localhost:8080/` and click the `Toggle deck.gl mode` button at the top. This will load a deck.gl instance and fit the map bounds to [the data](https://github.com/corrigancd/g6-in-react/blob/master/pages/data.js).

This gist helped me get things working:
https://gist.github.com/tomsoderlund/a2040d659aafe4064e4060f561aca6d1

Steps:

- In case someone else will find this useful, the fit bounds process can be started with an event. In the case of the question, when a new geoJSON has been successfully fetched. This could also be triggered when a user clicks an `auto-fit map to visible data` button, or in the example above, on deck.gl initialization, etc...
- Next, a helper function is used to calculate opposite corners of your bounds by passing an array of point type coordinates of data visible on your map:

  ```js
    fitBounds = (coords) => {
      let latMin = 90;
      let latMax = -90;
      let lonMin = 180;
      let lonMax = -180;
      coords.forEach(function (coord) {
        const RECT_LAT_INDEX = 'lat';
        const RECT_LON_INDEX = 'lon';
        if (coord[RECT_LAT_INDEX] < latMin) latMin = coord[RECT_LAT_INDEX];
        if (coord[RECT_LAT_INDEX] > latMax) latMax = coord[RECT_LAT_INDEX];
        if (coord[RECT_LON_INDEX] < lonMin) lonMin = coord[RECT_LON_INDEX];
        if (coord[RECT_LON_INDEX] > lonMax) lonMax = coord[RECT_LON_INDEX];
      });

      const bounds = [
        [lonMin, latMax],
        [lonMax, latMin],
      ];
      
      return bounds;
    }
  ```
- Create an instance of `WebMercatorViewport` and pass the same height and width parameters as your map;

```js
const view = new WebMercatorViewport({ width: 800, height: 600 });
```

- Call the `fitBounds` function on this `WebMercatorViewport` instance. The response will contain latitude, longitude and zoom attributes so I've destructured them below:

```js
const { latitude, longitude, zoom } = view.fitBounds(bounds)
```

- Set the latitude, longitude, zoom attriubtes on your map view state:

```js
  const INITIAL_VIEW_STATE = {
    latitude,
    longitude,
    zoom,
    maxZoom: 20, 
    pitch: 45,
    bearing: 0,
  };
```

- The map can then be rendered with something like:

```js
  return (
    <DeckGL
      layers={layers}
      initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE}
      controller={true}
    >
      <div style={COPYRIGHT_LICENSE_STYLE}>
        {"© "}
        <a
          style={LINK_STYLE}
          href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright"
          target="blank"
        >
          OpenStreetMap contributors
        </a>
      </div>
    </DeckGL>
  );
```

Padding can be added like below so that it fits nicely onto your map, something like:

```js
const { latitude, longitude, zoom } = new WebMercatorViewport({ width: 800, height: 600 }).fitBounds(bounds, { padding: { top: 100, bottom: 100, left: 100, right: 100 } })
```